# JSF Generic Validator

Tags: model-view-controller, jsf, richfaces

I want to write a generic validator  for checking name of a entity is exist or not.Currently i am doing this ,writing a new validator class  for  every Entity object,How can i specify Class type of entity bean dynamicly and write a generic validator for entity objects.

```
 public class LemfValidator implements Validator {
        public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent arg1,
                Object name) throws ValidatorException {
```

Comment: The functional requirement isn't fully clear. What exactly do you mean with "name of a entity"? Please elaborate.

Comment: @BalusC i find a post of you and use it thanks

Comment: I Use  f:attribute to pass parameter to validator.Along with uiconponent .

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is balusc post .It solve my problem.

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html